# javascript replace() function selecting symbols from string

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I'm sure somebody will be able to help me on this; I'm trying to replace :) with the word smiley - The following works but only replaces the first string:

```
var string = "hello :)";

string = string.replace(":)", "smiley");
```

I tried this but it won't work:

```
var string = "hello :)";

string = string.replace(/:)/g, "smiley");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with your second example, but the `/.../g` notation creates a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), and `)` has a special meaning in a regular expression; you need to "quote" or "escape" it with a backslash:

```
string = string.replace(/:\)/g, "smiley");
```